# Selecting element from a collection based on bitwise-and result

Tags: c++, performance, boost

I need to improve this section of code:

```
    uint32_t to_handle = 0;
    uint32_t test_const1 = Constraint3::VAL1 + Constraint3::VAL2;
    uint32_t test_const2 = Constraint1::VAL2 + Constraint1::VAL4 + Constraint1::VAL8;
    uint32_t test_const3 = Constraint2::VAL1 +  Constraint2::VAL2 + Constraint2::VAL4;

    to_handle = test_const1;

    for(ConstraintsContainer_t::iterator it = constraints_.begin(); it != constraints_.end(); ++it) {
        if( ( ((*it).get() & to_handle) == (*it).get() ) &&
                ( ((*it).get() & test_const2) == (*it).get() ) &&
                ( ((*it).get() & test_const3) == (*it).get() ) ) {
            choosen_.push_back((*it));
            to_handle -= (*it).get();
        }
    }
```

Here are declarations:

```
    namespace Constraint1 {
    typedef enum {
        NONE            = 0x00000000,
        VAL1            = 0x00000001,
        VAL2            = 0x00000002,
        VAL4            = 0x00000004,
        VAL8            = 0x00000008,
        ALL             = 0xFFFFFFFF
    } Type;
    }
    namespace Constraint2 {
    typedef enum {
        NONE            = 0x00000000,
        VAL1            = 0x00000001,
        VAL2            = 0x00000002,
        VAL4            = 0x00000004,
        VAL8            = 0x00000008,
        ALL             = 0xFFFFFFFF
    } Type;
    }
    namespace Constraint3 {
    typedef enum {
        NONE            = 0x00000000,
        VAL1            = 0x00000001,
        VAL2            = 0x00000002,
        VAL4            = 0x00000004,
        VAL8            = 0x00000008,
        VAL16           = 0x00000010,
        VAL32           = 0x00000020,
        ALL             = 0xFFFFFFFF
    } Type;
    }
    typedef std::vector  > ConstraintsContainer_t;
    ConstraintsContainer_t constraints_;
    ConstraintsContainer_t choosen_;
```

The goal is to select elements from a collection by performing a bitwise-and on them.

Order of insertion in that vector matters and number of element should reach about 100. It's currently taking about 50 microseconds to complete this section of codes, I'd need to make it 10-20 microseconds if possible.

Here is the source code on a live workspace if it helps:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=356a9d8c94bddf6721f98bbc44c74fec-71380fc8ea55c1ab9f744d79fff5379c

I've tryed to use boost multi_index_containers, but it'd require to get this to work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101886/boost-multi-index-container-with-composite-key-and-logical-and-comparison

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So to be chosen (the first time), the item has to be zero (`item & to_handle == item` with `to_handle=0`). Or is that meant to be `test_const1`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping! you're right `to_handle` is to be set to `test_const1` indeed

Comment: So, you set `to_handle = test_const1` somewhere? Or the first test is meant to be `item & test_const1 == item`?

Answer (score 1):

`to_handle` actually varies, but the `test_const`s are all constant, so we can give the compiler a hint here

```
const uint32_t test_const1 = Constraint3::VAL1 + Constraint3::VAL2;
const uint32_t test_const2 = Constraint1::VAL2 + Constraint1::VAL4 + Constraint1::VAL8;
const uint32_t test_const3 = Constraint2::VAL1 +  Constraint2::VAL2 + Constraint2::VAL4;

uint32_t to_handle = test_const1;
for(ConstraintsContainer_t::iterator it = constraints_.begin(); it != constraints_.end(); ++it) {
```

### EDIT

I've just seen from the *linked* code that the *posted* code is completely wrong. So, the remainder of this answer is unlikely to be helpful.

I will however observe that you're timing both the operations you sort-of show above, but *also* the formatted output. Are you sure you're timing the right thing?

---

now, we de-reference your iterator a lot in this loop. I don't know how easily the compiler can handle it here, but IMO this is more readable:

```
    auto &item = it->get();
```

(if you don't have C++11 `auto`, just put the actual type in - I don't know what it is here)

```
    if( (item & to_handle) == item &&
        (item & test_const2) == item &&
        (item & test_const3) == item ) {
        choosen_.push_back((*it));
        to_handle -= item;
    }
}
```

Now, the second two conditions in your `if` never vary, and they simply test that *all* the set bits of `item` are *inside both* masks `test_const2=0x0E` *and* `test_const3=0x07`. That is, *none* of the set bits are *outside* `test_const2 & test_const3`, so

```
const uint32_t fail_test = ~(test_const2 & test_const3);

//...

    if( (item & to_handle) == item &&
        (item & fail_test) == 0) {
        choosen_.push_back((*it));
        to_handle -= item;
    }
```

again, the optimizer might have figured that out already, but this version is anyway more expressive.

Comment: thanks again for helping! Sorry, I did not mention that this is supposed to process variable sets of (test_const1,test_const2,test_const3). But you're right, timing the display section is not really appropriate...

Comment: None of your posted (or linked) code process variable sets, only constant ones. Performance depends on the _actual code_, so showing two different versions, neither of which do the same thing you're trying to optimise, won't help you. FWIW though, setting the destination vector size in advance might help. It can't be bigger than the input, so `choosen_.reserve(constraints_.size())` before the loop (and timing start!) could help.

Comment: I get your point, maybe my post was not clear enough then: my question is as much about the specific ways of implementation (in my case: iterating over a complete vector) as the compiler optimization technics. So probably, this is not enough to state about the compiler optimization technics, but it should be enough to state about the various options of implementation (for example, indexed containers and if some feedback could confirm that this is viable, which kind and how)...

Comment: You're asking for help with designing an algorithm by asking us to review code that does something slightly different? You need to figure out the algorithm first, I'm afraid. Hammering your broken code until the algorithm makes sense is unlikely to work.